If everything was made for Jesus and through Jesus did Jesus take the rib from Adam and then make Eve?
John 1:3 All things were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was made.
Colossians 1:16 For by him were all things created, that are in heaven, and that are in earth, visible and invisible, whether they be thrones, or dominions, or principalities, or powers: all things were created by him, and for him:

Hey Titus! Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out the Help Center. Glad to have you.

'Jesus' did not take anything prior to being born in Bethlehem. No scripture supports that wording. Logos was in the beginning with God. And God was the Logos. And Colossians 1:15-17 referes to the antecedent 'the Father's . . .  dear Son' verses 12 to 14.

@NigelJ - I think you are being a little over-pedantic about the name Jesus.  If the Scripture says that Jesus created all things, then I can accept that.

@Dottard And can you quote those words from scripture ? It is matter of human nature and Divine nature. This is not a small (or 'pedantic') point. It is a matter of pious divinity.

@TitusTamum. Jesus attributed creation to God, not to himself. Mark 10:6.

John 1:3 All things were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was made. How do you skip over this?

@TitusTarnum. If Jesus is the Creator he would have said so plainly. He attributed creation to his God. Mark 13 :19.. No prophet  apostles, or patriarch has ever spoken or written about a God the word as the Creator. Jesus himself said he is the beginning of God's creation. That is the faithful and true witness himself telling us in Revelation 3:14.

NeverThirsty puts it this way:

God is unbelievably unique. He is a single being, and yet He is the
Father, Son, and the Holy Spirit simultaneously. Deut. 6:4 says that
God is “One,” but the Hebrew word that is translated as “One” in our
English Bibles refers to a plural being. God is a mystery. We should
not be surprised that we do not understand Him. We are not God. If
aliens existed on another planet and if they visited us, we probably
would discover that they are very different from us. Should we expect
God to be like us? Does God look like us? We know that He is a spirit.
He is a plural-one. God is the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit. So when
God created Adam and Eve, the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit all created
them. That is the meaning of Genesis 1:26.


Then God said, “Let Us make man in Our image, according to Our
likeness; and let them rule over the fish of the sea and over the
birds of the sky and over the cattle and over all the earth, and over
every creeping thing that creeps on the earth.” (NASB) Genesis 1:26

Father & Spirit Created

Genesis 1:1 - God created everything

Genesis 1:2 - Holy Spirit existed before Adam and Eve and was present and actively involved in the creation also.

Psalm 104:30 - Holy Spirit being involved in the creation


The Son Created (The "Logos" with God)

He is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn of all creation.
For by Him all things were created, both in the heavens and on earth,
visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or
authorities– all things have been created through Him and for Him. He
is before all things, and in Him all things hold together. (NASB)
Colossians 1:15-17

Then I looked, and I heard the voice of many angels around the throne
and the living creatures and the elders; and the number of them was
myriads of myriads, and thousands of thousands, saying with a loud
voice, “Worthy is the Lamb that was slain to receive power and riches
and wisdom and might and honor and glory and blessing.” And every
created thing which is in heaven and on the earth and under the earth
and on the sea, and all things in them, I heard saying, “To Him who
sits on the throne, and to the Lamb, be blessing and honor and glory
and dominion forever and ever.” (NASB) Revelation 5:11-13


Conclusion: The Son was involved in all of creation.

The answer will depend on ones' theology. No answer on SE-BH should 'depend on one's theology'. This is an hermeneutic site.

Colossians 1:15-17 refer to the antecedent 'the Father's . . .  dear Son' verses 12-14. The name 'Jesus' is inappropriate in this place (in reference to creation).

'Jesus' is the name given to the child of Mary. The question is about creation. Therefore that nomenclature is inappropriate. Scripture tells us things about the Son of God and about Logos and about Jesus. But the names and titles are not interchangeable at will. They all have specific meaning and concept.

The record indicates that God created. And the Logos was with God (in the beginning). And God was the Logos. It is really wrong to muddle the human nature of Jesus with that aspect (of the Divine Person) which is termed 'Logos'. It is irreverent to muddle these Divine things up. And it also shows an inappropriate, sentimental attachment to 'jesus' (I deliberately leave off the capital to accentuate the idolatry involved).

@NigelJ I have edited it once again.

Disciplined hermeneutic principles will actually prevent us from making theological mistakes, if we apply them correctly. I appreciate your editing.

The Christ existed before the creation of Jesus body, and we call him Jesus Christ?Philippians 2:5 Let this mind be in you, which was also in Christ Jesus:
Philippians 2:6 Who, being in the form of God, thought it not robbery to be equal with God:
Philippians 2:7 But made himself of no reputation, and took upon him the form of a servant, and was made in the likeness of men:                       1 Corinthians 10:4 And did all drink the same spiritual drink: for they drank of that spiritual Rock that followed them: and that Rock was Christ.


… did Jesus take the rib from Adam and then make Eve?

The simple answer is "yes" (though he didn't go by that name at the time).
The supernatural being that was later incarnated as Jesus was the same being that interacted with humanity throughout the Hebrew Scriptures.

The Son was "YHWH", the Rock of Israel, the God of the Old Testament.
The Father was revealed by Jesus in the New Testament, and generally unknown until then.

See my answers to:

contradiction - Has anyone seen God or not?.
contradiction - How can John 1:18 say that "No man has seen God" when the Bible says that Abraham, Moses, Job and others have?.


+1. Good succinct answer and to the point.

A rock by any other name still might give you water in the desert

While I generally agree with this answer, there are a few exception such as Ps 110:1 where YHWH is clearly the Father.

@Dottard refers to "Ps 110:1" — Agreed (which is why I said "generally unknown"). But I'm sure that most people at the time were totally unaware of the significance implied by this verse.
